# Parsing Data from Access to Excel via vba code to split onto sheets based on field contents

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have been trying to find a way to adapt the code i have written (based heavily on the Youtube video and coding provided by Access Jitsu to split my data across mutliple sheets based on the value in one field. 
I have a number of fields and the purpose is for a comparison between invoicing and costs which i want to split by years onto separate sheets in excel.

Can anyone assist with how i would parse the field to split the data onto individual sheets based on the Year (in the code [Yr]) field.

many thanks in advance.

Code below. couldnt get it to display as all one entry

```
Private Sub Command2_Click()
On Error GoTo SubError

Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SQL As String
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer

'Show user work is being performed
DoCmd.Hourglass (True)

'*********************************************
'              RETRIEVE DATA
'*********************************************
'SQL statement to retrieve data from database
SQL = "SELECT [Job Opened], [Job Number], [Job Title], " & _
"[ProposalRef], [QuotedValue], [Invoiced], " & _
"[Uplifted Cost], [Profit], [Diff], [Last Date Worked], [Reason], [Status], [Yr]" & _
"FROM [BIID] " & _
"ORDER BY [Job Number] "


'Execute query and populate recordset
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

'If no data, don't bother opening Excel, just quit
If rs1.RecordCount = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No data selected for export", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "No data exported"
    GoTo SubExit
End If

'*********************************************
'             BUILD SPREADSHEET
'*********************************************
'Create an instance of Excel and start building a spreadsheet

'Early Binding
Set xlApp = Excel.Application

xlApp.Visible = False
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add
Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets(1)

With xlSheet
    .Name = "BIID-All"
    .Cells.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    .Cells.Font.Size = 10

    'Set column widths
    .Columns("A").ColumnWidth = 11
    .Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 10
    .Columns("C").ColumnWidth = 40
    .Columns("D").ColumnWidth = 16
    .Columns("E").ColumnWidth = 14
    .Columns("F").ColumnWidth = 12
    .Columns("G").ColumnWidth = 12
    .Columns("H").ColumnWidth = 12
    .Columns("I").ColumnWidth = 10
    .Columns("J").ColumnWidth = 15
    .Columns("K").ColumnWidth = 45
    .Columns("L").ColumnWidth = 8
    .Columns("M").ColumnWidth = 5

    'Format columns
    .Columns("A").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    .Columns("J").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    .Columns("F").NumberFormat = "£#,###,##0.00;-£#,###,##0.00"
    .Columns("G").NumberFormat = "£#,###,##0.00;-£#,###,##0.00"
    .Columns("H").NumberFormat = "£#,###,##0.00;-£#,###,##0.00"
    .Columns("I").NumberFormat = "#,###,##0.00%;-#,###,##0.00%"

    'Column Headings
    .Range("A2").Value = "Date Opened"
    .Range("B2").Value = "Job Number"
    .Range("C2").Value = "Job Title"
    .Range("D2").Value = "Proposal Ref."
    .Range("E2").Value = "Quoted Value"
    .Range("F2").Value = "Total Invoiced"
    .Range("G2").Value = "Uplifted Cost"
    .Range("H2").Value = "Proft"
    .Range("I2").Value = "Difference"
    .Range("J2").Value = "Last Date Worked"
    .Range("K2").Value = "Reason"
    .Range("L2").Value = "Status"
    .Range("M2").Value = "Year"

    .Range("A1").Value = "Date Updated"
    .Range("B1").Value = Date

    'Format Column Headings
    .Range("A2:M2").Cells.Font.Bold = True
    .Range("A2:M2").Cells.Font.Color = RGB(68, 84, 106)
    .Range("A2:B2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    .Range("E2:J2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

    'provide initial value to row counter
    i = 3
    'Loop through recordset and copy date from recordset to sheet
    Do While Not rs1.EOF

        .Range("A" & i).Value = rs1![Job Opened]
        .Range("B" & i).Value = rs1![Job Number]
        .Range("C" & i).Value = rs1![Job Title]
        .Range("D" & i).Value = rs1![ProposalRef]
        .Range("E" & i).Value = rs1![QuotedValue]
        .Range("F" & i).Value = rs1![Invoiced]
        .Range("G" & i).Value = rs1![Uplifted Cost]
        .Range("H" & i).Value = rs1![Profit]
        .Range("I" & i).Value = rs1![Diff]
        .Range("J" & i).Value = rs1![Last Date Worked]
        .Range("K" & i).Value = rs1![Reason]
        .Range("L" & i).Value = rs1![Status]
        .Range("M" & i).Value = rs1![Yr]

        i = i + 1
        rs1.MoveNext

        Loop

        'Total Average %
        .Range("F" & i).HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .Range("F" & i, "H" & i).Merge
        .Range("F" & i).Value = "Average % Profit (Billed vs Uplifted Cost)"
        .Range("F" & i).Cells.Font.Bold = True
        .Range("I" & i).Formula = "=AVERAGE(I3:I" & i - 1

        'Add borders
        .Range("A2:M2").Borders(xlEdgeTop).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("A2:M2").Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("A2:A" & i - 1).Borders(xlEdgeLeft).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("A2:M" & i - 1).Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("A2:M" & i - 1).Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous
        .Range("A2:M" & i - 1).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).LineStyle = XlLineStyle.xlContinuous

        'Add Conditional formatting
        With .Range("I3:I" & i).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlGreater, 0)
            .Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        End With
        With .Range("I3:I" & i).FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlLess, 0)
            .Font.Color = vbRed
        End With

    End With

SubExit:
On Error Resume Next
DoCmd.Hourglass False
xlApp.Visible = True
rs1.Close
Set rs1 = Nothing
Exit Sub

 SubError:
MsgBox "Error Number: " & Err.Number & "= " & Err.Description, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, _
    "An error occurred"
GoTo SubExit
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to introduce a new recordset that has a list of the distinct years in. You then loop this recordset, adding a new worksheet for each year, and then your original recordset is opened, but has a `WHERE` clause in the SQL to just show data for the year in question. Some abridged VBA to do this is below:

```
Sub sSampleExport()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsYear As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim objXL As New Excel.Application
    Dim objXLBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim objXLSheet As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lngLoop1 As Long
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Yr FROM BIID ORDER BY Yr ASC;"
    Set rsYear = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
    If Not (rsYear.BOF And rsYear.EOF) Then
        Set objXLBook = objXL.Workbooks.Add
        Do
            Set objXLSheet = objXLBook.Worksheets.Add(After:=objXLBook.Worksheets(objXLBook.Worksheets.Count))
            With objXLSheet
                .name = rsYear!Yr
                strSQL = "SELECT [Job Opened], [Job Number], [Job Title] " _
                    & " FROM BIID " _
                    & " WHERE Yr=" & rsYear!Yr
                Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
                If Not (rsData.BOF And rsData.EOF) Then
                    .Cells(1, 1).CopyFromRecordset rsData
                End If
            End With
            rsYear.MoveNext
        Loop Until rsYear.EOF
        For lngLoop1= objXLBook.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
            If Left(objXLBook.Worksheets(lngLoop1).Name, 5) = "Sheet" Then
                objXLBook.Worksheets(lngLoop1).Delete
            End If
        Next lngLoop1
        objXLBook.Worksheets(1).Select
        objXLBook.SaveAs "J:\downloads\test.xlsx"
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsData.Close
    rsYear.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    Set rsYear = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Set objXLSheet = Nothing
    objXLBook.Close
    Set objXLBook = Nothing
    objXL.Quit
    Set objXL = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sSampleExport", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Regards,

Comment: Applecore - firstly many thanks. Unfortunately, although i have spent a fair bit of time working with access and sql-server i have so far to date tried to avoid the vba side as it is a complete different set of rules. As noted in my original post i cribbed most of the code, making edits for the Select and formatting type areas once i had the basic data correct (and after a few tries). As such i understand the principle of what you have said but am not sure how to integrate the coding with my own and i tried copying the code to run from my click command button (changing output) and it fails.

Comment: sorry to have to ask but am a real novice when it comes to code and try to learn from working examples where i can so i can see how the code behaves but as i cannot get the code to work on a new command I am not sure how to then add the appropriate bits into my own.

Comment: The best thing to do is to take the code that I have posted, add it to a new command button, run it, and inspect the output. Then add the other fields that you need to the "inner" recordset `rsData` to get all of the information into Excel. Finally add the formatting required that was present in your initial code.

Comment: Also, when you say that the code "fails" please give more details - what was the error message and which line of code did it occur on, so that people can troubleshoot it.

Comment: I had another look to see what the issue was and having gone through the copy and edits again, it appears the code you provided was referencing Excel 15.0 library where i only have 14.0. I have re-assigned the reference and it produced an output so will try to finish off the remaining code myself. Again, many thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Applecore - that has worked perfecrtly thanks. for tidiness my only question would be how do i tell excel to remove the default 3 sheets when it create the new workbook. Also is there a way of thanking via a ranking system on this site or similar so i can show appreciation that way

Comment: I've amended the code to delete any sheet that starts with "Sheet" (it is not always 3, depending on the user). Just mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Piece of advice, this:

```
Do While Not rs1.EOF

    .Range("A" & i).Value = rs1![Job Opened]
    .Range("B" & i).Value = rs1![Job Number]
    .Range("C" & i).Value = rs1![Job Title]
    .Range("D" & i).Value = rs1![ProposalRef]
    .Range("E" & i).Value = rs1![QuotedValue]
    .Range("F" & i).Value = rs1![Invoiced]
    .Range("G" & i).Value = rs1![Uplifted Cost]
    .Range("H" & i).Value = rs1![Profit]
    .Range("I" & i).Value = rs1![Diff]
    .Range("J" & i).Value = rs1![Last Date Worked]
    .Range("K" & i).Value = rs1![Reason]
    .Range("L" & i).Value = rs1![Status]
    .Range("M" & i).Value = rs1![Yr]

    i = i + 1
    rs1.MoveNext

Loop
```

can be shortened to this:

```
.Range("A" & i).CopyFromRecordset rs1
```

Comment: jamheadart - many thanks for the information. This would use all variables from the recordset. ideally I won't actually be showing the "Yr" field as that would be a divider rather than a significant field but useful to know for other projects

Comment: My suggestion would be to do the query multiple times and have a `WHERE` clause to pull data per year (without pulling the year itself), and then use the CopyFromRecordset to get the details onto your table, rather than pulling ALL info and filtering it on Excel-side.

Comment: I think AppleCore's answer is doing this exact thing so try that.